# SignalR hubConnection.on is not working. Clients.Others.SendAsync and hubConnection.on are not communicating well

Tags: .net, angular, signalr

I'm currently trying to build an app that involves SignalR's hub connection functionality. Eventually, I want to enable the app to handle real-time chats, but first I want to check if the basic part of SignalR works.

I'm trying to ensure that a toastr that notifies about the hub connection is displayed when a user logs in, but the problem is that the toastr is not displayed. Here are some pieces of my code.

**[PresenceHub.cs]**

```
public class PresenceHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ILogger<PresenceHub> _logger;
    public PresenceHub(ILogger<PresenceHub> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(Context.User.GetUserName());
        await Clients.Others.SendAsync("UserIsOnline", Context.User.GetUserName());
    }
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await Clients.Others.SendAsync("UserIsOffline", Context.User.GetUserName());

        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
...
```

**[presence.service.ts]**

```
export class PresenceService {
  hubUrl = environment.hubUrl; 
  private hubConnection: HubConnection

  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  createHubConnection(user: User){
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.hubUrl + 'presence', {
        accessTokenFactory: () => user.token
      })
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build()
    
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("hubConnection started for " + user.username);
        console.log("user token: " + user.token);
        this.toastr.success("Inside the createHubConnection")
      }) 
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
    
    this.hubConnection.on('UserIsOnline', username => { 
      console.log(username + ' has connected'); 
      this.toastr.success(username + 'has connected');
    })

    this.hubConnection.on('UserIsOffline', username => {
      console.log(username + ' has disconnected'); 
      this.toastr.success(username + ' has disconnected');
    })
...
```

By the code above, I've confirmed that

- The logger placed in `OnConnectedAsync` in `PresenceHub.cs` displays the fetched username, which means that this method is properly called.
- user. token in console.log gets properly displayed, which means that the  `new HubConnectionBuilder()` part was successful.
- The toastr in `this. hub connection. start` in `presence.service.ts` gets successfully called, which means that the problem doesn't lie in toastr itself.
- The spelling of `UserIsOnline` both in `PresenceHub.cs` and `presence.service.ts` match.
  etc.

Any idea what other possibilities I should investigate?

Comment: There was an edit suggestion to change ```PresenceHub.cs```  to ```PresenceHub.ts```, but it's a wrong suggestion. I'm writing the backend in .Net, which explains the reason why it's cs (C#), not ts (TypeScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `Clients.Others` on the server side. This means send this message to all **other** connections, not yours. You're either wanting `Clients.Caller` if you want to send a message to yourself, or `Clients.All` to send a message to all connections.

Additionally, you should move `this.hubConnection.on('UserIsOnline', ...)` to be before `this.hubConnection.start()` to remove the possible race condition of the server responding before your method is registered on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That got the program to display the "{username} has connected" toastr when logging in. One thing that I'm wondering about is why it doesn't work when I try to do the same with 'UserIsOffline' with "{username} has disconnected", which I want to display when the user has logged out.

Comment: Because you're running that method when the client is disconnected, so it wont receive the client method call.

Comment: Then how can I have the 'disconnected' message displayed as well?